# R Prompt User With Autocomplete

Tags: r, gwidgets

Is there a way in R to prompt a user (i.e. scanf) for information and also allow auto-completion of that prompt using an array of strings as possible completions?

Basically, looking for something like GNU Readline for R (ideally with an example).

Comment: If there is nothing like this , I would also be interested in other ways that user my easily select things from a long list -- I guess printing an "# index : "string" list and having the user select the number would be the most ... `BASIC` ;-)

Comment: Ah, just found `select.list` as part of the `utils` which does what I just described in my above comment.

Comment: Kyle, go ahead and post your solution as an answer, in case others are seeking for this tool.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: Well it doesn't support auto complete, so I wouldn't really call it a solution to my question. If something isn't posted in a day or so though I will turn it into an answer.

Answer (score 5):

The autocomplete for function names, etc., seems to be a property of the development environment that is running R.  So it works slightly differently in R GUI compared to eclipse compared to emacs compared to RStudio compared to whatever.

From that, I think you may struggle to get autocomplete working in a portable way for `scanf`/`readline` without substantial hackery.

A better solution would be to create your own GUI, where you control the behaviour.  Here's an example using `gWidgets`, with a dropdown list (aka combobox) whose choices reduce depending upon what is typed into it.

```
library(gWidgetstcltk) # or gWidgetsRGtk2, etc.
#some choices to complete to
choices <- c("football", "barometer", "bazooka")

#sort to make it easier for the user to find one, and 
#prepend with a blank string to type in
items <- c("", sort(choices))

#create a gui
win <- gwindow()
drp <- gdroplist(items = items, editable = TRUE, cont = win)

#When the user types something, update the list of available items 
#to those that begin with what has been typed.
addHandlerKeystroke(drp, handler = function(h, ...)
{
  regex <- paste("^", svalue(h$obj), sep = "")
  h$obj[] <- items[grepl(regex, items)]
})
```

Inside that handler, `h$obj` refers to the dropdown list widget, `svalue(h$obj)` is the currently selected value and `h$obj[]` is the set of items.

---

The autocompletion in R GUI (and possibly others) is built upon a set of functions in the `utils` package (see `?rcompgen`).  Digging through the source of that may be useful, but I still think it will be hard to get it working while you are retrieving user input, in a way that is portable between development enivronments.  (I'd be happy to be proved wrong though.)

Comment: RStudio implements auto-completion, and is open source. Maybe the OP can borrow from that?

Comment: none of these gWidgets packages are available on CRAN now

Comment: Yeah, gWidgets is obsolete now - use Shiny for any dashboarding needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort of do this with rstudioapi

```
choices = list(test=\(){cat("test")})
rstudioapi::sendToConsole("choices$",execute = F)
```

pressing tab now has autocomplete options that run associated functions.